# How to Click link in iframe using New Relic Synthetic

Tags: selenium, performance, monitoring, newrelic

```
.then(function(){ 
  $browser.switchTo().frame('tool_content');
 })
.then(function(){ $browser.sleep(9000) })
.then(function () {
  log('clickElement "Course Home Manager"');
return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("moreIns"), DefaultTimeout); })
.then(function (el) { el.click(); })
```

I am new for New Relic,
I am trying to click button in iframe using New Relic Synthetic but always  coming "nvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string " error

Answer (score 0):

New Relic Synthetics supports async/await now - here is an example of how to switch to a frame when it becomes available on the page:

```html
const url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp';


async function main() {
  await $webDriver.get(url);
  await $webDriver.wait($selenium.until.ableToSwitchToFrame($selenium.By.xpath("//iframe[@name='adreporter']")), 10000);
  //let elementToClick = await $webDriver.findElement($selenium.By.id('someid'));
  //elementToClick.click();
}

main();
```

I would also recommend checking out the docs that have all available functions you can use in the Synthetics runtime environment: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/scripting-monitors/synthetic-scripted-browser-reference-monitor-versions-chrome-100#until